# Why dbWriteTable in R is not able to write data in non default schema in HANA?

Tags: r, jdbc, hana

Why dbWriteTable is not able to write data in non default schema in HANA?

```
dbcConnection_Test1 <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:sap://crbwhd12:30215?SCHEMA_NAME/TABLE_NAME", "Username", "Password")

dbWriteTable(jdbcConnection_Test1, name = "TABLE_NAME", value = DataFrame1, overwrite = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

I have established connection between R and HANA.

Then I have specified HANA Table name in which the data needs to be updated.

I am getting an error message saying that the table name is invalid and it is not available in the default schema. I want to upload the data in some other schema

Comment: Putting in SCHEMA_NAME/TABLE_NAME into the connect URL is wrong. That should not even connect successfully. To address a non-current schema object just use the common notation `“SCHEMA_NAME”.”OBJECT_NAME”`.

Comment: If you could include a past of the error message in your question that would be helpful.

Comment: Hello Mark,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         The error was: 
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (SAP DBTech JDBC: [259] (at 11): invalid table name: ABC_TABLE: line 1 col 12 (at pos 11))

Comment: Hello Lars, I had already tried the syntax given by you. That is also showing error.